# how to get my popup to work with a dynamic class

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to create a popup where depending on the class the respective modal will popup. The popup has a dynamic class. So if I have a class called
popup_1 then it should show popup_modal_1

```
@foreach($single_portfolio->portfolio as $portfolio)
    <h2>{!! $portfolio->title !!}</h2>

    <?php
        $thumb = $portfolio->image;
    ?>


    <div class="popup popup_{!! $portfolio->id !!}">
        <img src="{!! asset("portfolio_images/thumbs/$thumb") !!}">
    </div>

    <div id="myModal" class="popup_modal popup_modal_{!! $portfolio->id !!}">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <span class="close">
                &times;
            </span>

            <div class="portfolio_popup">
                <div class="portfolio_wrapper">
                    <?php
                        $fullImage = $portfolio->image2;
                        $fullImg = $portfolio->image2;
                    ?>

                    <div>
                        <img src="{!! asset("portfolio_images/$img") !!}">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="portfolio_nav">
                    <div>
                        <img src="{!! asset("portfolio_images/$thumbImg") !!}">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@endforeach
```

My JS

```
$('.popup').click(function(){
    $('.popup_modal').show();
});
```

Comment: In such a case it would probably make more sense to select the correct element based on DOM structure- like looking for the next sibling of the clicked element. And btw., you are producing invalid HTML here, because you are using IDs in a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like:

```
$('.popup').click(function(){
    $(this).next('.popup_modal').show(); //assuming that associated popup_modal will be immediate to your popup link
});
```